# Admob keeps telling me my App does not meet guideline requirements

Tags: android, navigation, admob, ads, usability

I wanted to include some ads in my first app for Android, but Admob deactivated them. Reason: "Site Behaviour: navigation." I tried several things to solve it, but it still doesnt meet the requirements by Admob and i dont know why. Reading the guidelines wasnt helpful, I don't know what exactly is wrong with the navigation for the user in my App. Maybe my app is not applicable for ads, because its a tool for a game with dynamic content. Im happy for every idea you have what the cause of the problem could be.

You cant find my app here: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.moriruec.ow_companion&hl=de

it has 2 banner ads at the bottom of 2 Activities.

I already repositioned the floating action button so that there is more space between the banner and the button

If the game is not installed you will be redirected to the play store page of the app, in previous versions nothing happened when you clicked on "go to game"

[image]

[image]

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
   xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
   android:layout_width="match_parent"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   tools:context=".MainActivity">

   <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
       android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:layout_marginBottom="52dp"
       tools:listitem="@layout/datasetitem" />


   <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
       android:id="@+id/button_compare"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
       android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
       android:layout_marginBottom="148dp"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_compare_arrows_black_24dp"
       android:visibility="invisible"
       app:backgroundTint="@color/red" />

   <com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
       android:id="@+id/button_add_dataset"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
       android:layout_marginBottom="78dp"
       android:layout_marginEnd="22dp"
       android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_24dp"
       app:backgroundTint="@color/red" />


   <RelativeLayout
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent">

             <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
                 android:id="@+id/adView"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                 android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                 ads:adSize="BANNER"
                 ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-7240053507946831/3541202378"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>


       <!--  ads:adUnitId="ca-app-pub-3940256099942544/6300978111"></com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>  -->



  </RelativeLayout>


</androidx.coordinatorlayout.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can Try to add Banner ad inside recyclerview item. You Can [check](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-ads/tree/master/advanced/BannerRecyclerViewExample) this out.

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I edited my post with the layout xml im am using. But the ad was showing for two weeks, everything was fine. But Admob decided that my app does not meet the requirements, thats why you cannot see the banner in my app at the moment. Something must be against the guidelines but I cannot figure out what it is

Answer (score 0):

i think you have to remove the relativelyout where you have the adview. because the with and height are also set to match-parent, which took all the screen.

otherwise, you have to be sure that you banner ad don't show above your listview. because it's a violation of admob policy.

Ads are not allowed to show above the content of your app.

Answer (score 0):

Use relative layout and place the recyclerview above adview. Sometime adview cover the contents of the app and user can not interact with all contents. Make sure there is noting below the banner ad.